# DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS out of whack in Oracle when moving partition or subpartition segments

Tags: oracle, statistics, oracle-19c

I've observed that when moving a partition or subpartition of a table (`ALTER TABLE xyz MOVE PARTITION abc`), the row count of the moved segment gets reflected in `DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS` at higher levels (at the table level for partition moves, or both the table and partition level for subpartition moves) as `DELETES`, **but not as `INSERTS`**, creating a mathematical imbalance.

Ostensibly, the `DELETES` count is because a new segment was created and the old one dropped. The dropped segment explains the `DELETES` being counted, and is also shown by the `DROP_SEGMENTS` counter. But a new segment took its place (this is a *move*), so to keep it balanced it should register the same row count in the `INSERTS` column (`+100 - 100 = net 0`). But it doesn't.

As a result, if you take a 100 row table and move a partition that has 10 rows in it, and repeat the move over and over 100 times, you will have `10*100 = 1000 DELETES` and `0 INSERTS`, so a total difference of -1000 rows off the statistics baseline. But of course that's impossible. It's only a 100 row table. The formula `NUM_ROWS + (INSERTS - DELETES)` is broken.

Has anyone figured out where the missing `INSERT` numbers are? Or, any other way to estimate current row count since `NUM_ROWS + (INSERTS - DELETES)` doesn't work in these circumstances? Yes, I know that gathering stats at the appropriate granularity will zero it all out, but I cannot assume stats gathering. I have to be able to interpret the numbers as they are without interference and still come up with a good row count estimate.

I'm using 19c, primarily, but this applies as well to earlier versions back to 11g.